# Scrolling one element from a sibling element within a page

Tags: javascript, scroll

From within an iframe I must scroll another.  The scrolling location is the href attribute of an  tag. I am able to get to the element #ftoc which contains the document that I want to scroll, an html file located on the same domain.

I have this code to do the scrolling.

```
$('#cfrench', window.parent.parent.document).contents().find('#ftoc').contents().find('body').animate({scrollTop: $('a[href="'+text+'"]').offset().top-1},500);
```

There seems to be a problem with `.contents().find('body')`.  What is the right way of scrolling to that href?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [this](http://oncemade.com/animated-page-scroll-with-jquery/) version

```
var elementClicked = $('a[href="' + text + '"]');
var destination = $(elementClicked).offset().top;
var $frame = $('#cfrench', window.parent.parent.document).contents().find('#ftoc').contents();
$frame.find("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination - 20 }, 500);
```

p.s. I wasn't able to check the code because I don't the details.

**version 2.0 :) (working solution)**

**main.html**

```
<iframe id="frame1" src="page-1.htm"></iframe>
<iframe id="frame2" src="page-2.htm"></iframe>
```

**page-1.html**

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #anchor { margin-top:400px; display:block; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#scroller').click(function () {

                var $frame = $(window.parent.document).find('#frame2').contents();
                var $anchor = $frame.find('#anchor');


                var destination = $anchor.offset().top;

                console.log(destination);
                $frame.find("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination - 20 }, 500);

                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Page 1
    <a id="scroller" href="#">Scroll iframe</a>
</body>
```

**page-2.html**

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #anchor { margin:400px 0; display:block; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    Page 2
    <a id="anchor" href="anhor.html">Anchor</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  It still doesn't scroll but I will debug it more.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will look at this and try to transfer the mechanism to my page.

Comment: If you will need sources let me know how I can deliver it to you

Comment: I made three files with the code you have here and couldn't get scrolling.

Comment: have you put the `jquery-1.6.2.min.js` file in the same folder?